# Using Task.Factory.StartNew inside a object with lock

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is there hidden dangers in using multithreading inside an object locked with lock?

Explanation:

I am writing an Add-in for Outlook, where mails can be translated from 3 other languages, because the mail-thread will have multi-language content. The (language) dictionaries are placed in a common Container object. Those dictionaries are very large and depended on reading the words for translations from language specific files.

When several mails are open they will call the same Container-object for translations. To prevent two or more mail to modify the Container-object an the language dictionaries simultaneously, I use lock in the method call. Because every mail can have content from several languages I want to make the file access to the different language files in parallel for better performance and user experience.

```
Dictionary<LanguageType, LanguageDictionary> Dictionaries;
Dictionary<Language, List<Words>> NewWords;
public void UpdatelanguageDictionaries()
{
    lock(_lock)
    {
       DoStuff();

       int i = 0;
       Task[] tasks = new Task[3];
       foreach(KeyvaluePair<LanguageType, LanguageDictionary> kvp in Dictionaries)
       {
          tasks[i] = TaskFactory.StartNew(() => kvp.Value.UpdateFromFile(NewWords[kvp.Key]));
          i++;
       }
       Task.WaitAll();

       DoMoreStuff();
     }
}
```

First I tried using multithreading with **await** and **async**, but that's not aloud inside a lock statement (indication trouble with multithreading inside lock).

The code works as expected, but sometimes there occur errors which seems to be unrelated to the multithreading part, but doesn't occur when I run the UpdateFromFile(); in sequence. Errors due to multithreading is also know to be hard to identify, so I won't not a lots of time to identify an error if it's just a bad idea to use multithreading inside a lock.

So is it save to run multithreaded code inside a lock statement or should I avoid it?

Comment: *Don't* use locks in the first place. If you want to modify a dictionary concurrently use `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of locking a normal Dictionary. In this case though it looks like you don't really need locking at that level. The thing that needs locking is the `Value` object that calls `UpdateFromFile`. The dictionary itself doesn't change

Comment: An easier and safer technique would be to load the file contents separately, create the new dictionary object and then replace the old dictionary with a new one.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for your comment. The container object i am using has other content, which demands that I am using a lock.

Comment: Why? If you *didn't* modify the dictionary's contents you wouldn't need locking. Locking at the method level won't prevent incorrect modifications to the `LanguageDictionary` instances

Comment: That lock won't prevent client threads from reading mixed contents either. It only prevents multiple threads from updating `Dictionaries`. It doesn't prevent clients from reading half-loaded entries. That's why load-and-replace is safer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I do modify the content of the dictionaries. I have other variables in the Container-object which are modified too, but because there is no disk access, i don't have performance issues here.

Comment: The problem isn't performance, it's correctness. This code isn't correct. It can't be made correct either unless you serialize any access to the dictionary *values* inside `LanguageDictionary` itself.

Comment: If Outlook tried to read from that dictionary while `UpdatelanguageDictionaries` was running you could end up with one old and one new translation.

Comment: Each language has about 150K words, so the words has  to loaded when a mail needs that word. For a Mail it's not a question about the dictionaries are new or old, but if they are complete for their purpose. So the dictionaries must contain the sum of the needs for the mails.

Comment: Consider using an AsyncLock instead, see https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock